# Cropping bitmap using sourceRect in createJS isn't working

Tags: easeljs, createjs

So I want to crop a image, the dimension is 400px and it is in library of flash professional with the name img1.

```
puzzlePieceBmp = new createjs.Bitmap(new lib.img1())
puzzlePieceBmp.sourceRect = new createjs.Rectangle( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
stage.addChild(puzzlePieceBmp.image)
```

The image appears always in one piece, no matter what I choose for the sourceRect. Am I doing something wrong? When I look up in the console, the sourceRect has the dimensions I defined. And I confirmed that the stage is updated.

Comment: Firstly, the code you posted should generate an error. You should be adding the Bitmap to the stage, not the Image: `stage.addChild(puzzlePieceBmp);`. You are likely doing something else incorrectly, as sourceRect appears to be working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/dhkvxz5a/

Comment: @gskinner Nothing shows up if I use stage.addChild(puzzlePieceBmp) and there is no error.

Comment: You're going to have to isolate your issue further. As demonstrated in my example above, sourceRect works using the code you provided. Are you sure your image isn't empty in the top right corner or something?

Comment: the only difference is that you are requesting a image from a file and I am requesting from the flash professional library

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've changed the settings, the assets in the exported "lib" object are all display object symbols. Images are accessible via the "img" object.

So, what your code is doing, is creating a new "img1" Bitmap instance, trying to make it the source image for a second Bitmap instance, adding a source rect to that second Bitmap, then adding the original "img1" Bitmap (without a sourceRect) onto the stage (by accessing bmp.image).

To fix this, just get rid of the second Bitmap:

`puzzlePieceBmp = new lib.img1(); // this creates a Bitmap, not an Image
puzzlePieceBmp.sourceRect = new createjs.Rectangle( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
stage.addChild(puzzlePieceBmp);`

Comment: I solved this problem, I unchecked "Export all bitmaps as Spritesheets" and used the same code you gave me. Thanks